# LateInitializationError hive using bloc

Tags: flutter, hive, bloc

> ======== Exception caught by widgets library ======================================================= The following LateError was thrown building KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#74540]:
> LateInitializationError: Field '_persondb' has not been initialized.
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:    Scaffold
> Scaffold:file:///C:/Users/Prive/StudioProjects/tanja/lib/person/screens/personsScreen/personsSreen.dart:18:16
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/*internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart
> 266:49      throw*
> packages/tanja/person/personService/personService.dart 6:22
> get [_persondb] packages/tanja/person/personService/personService.dart
> 15:31
> getPersons
> mount
>
> ........................

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:tanja/person/personService/personService.dart';
import 'package:tanja/route.dart';

void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiRepositoryProvider(
      providers: [
        RepositoryProvider(create: (context) => PersonService().getPersons()),
      ],
      child:   MaterialApp.router(
        routerConfig: goRouter,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**service**

```
import '../personmodel/personDB.dart';

class PersonService {
  late Box<PersonDB> _persondb;

  Future<void> init() async {
    if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(0)) {
      Hive.registerAdapter(PersonDBAdapter());
    }
    _persondb = await Hive.openBox<PersonDB>('persondb');
  }
  List<PersonDB> getPersons() {
    final persons = _persondb.values;
    return persons.toList();
  }

  void addPerson(final PersonDB personDB ) {
    _persondb.add(personDB);
  }
}
```

**bloc**

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:tanja/person/personService/personService.dart';

import '../../../personmodel/personDB.dart';


part 'persons_state.dart';

class PersonsCubit extends Cubit<PersonsState> {
  PersonService _personService;
  PersonsCubit(this._personService) : super(PersonsInitial());

  void loadPersonsData(){
    _personService.init();
    emit(PersonsDataLoaded(_personService.getPersons()));
  }
}
```

**screen**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:tanja/person/screens/personsScreen/bloc/persons_cubit.dart';

import '../../personService/personService.dart';


class PersonsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const PersonsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PersonService  _personService= PersonService();
    return BlocProvider(
        create: (context){
          return PersonsCubit(_personService)..loadPersonsData();
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: BlocBuilder<PersonsCubit,PersonsState>(
              builder:(context, state) {
            if(state is PersonsInitial){
              return Text('$state');
            }else{
              return Text('$state');
            }
          }),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is from the loadPersonsData() function in the PersonsCubit class,  `_personService.init();` return a Future therefore the `emit(PersonsDataLoaded(_personService.getPersons()));` must wait for it to init completely to call `_personService.getPersons()`.
You could try to fix the loadPersonsData function as following:

```dart
Future<void> loadPersonsData() async {
    await _personService.init();
    emit(PersonsDataLoaded(_personService.getPersons()));
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//replace 
//late Box<PersonDB> _persondb;
//to this
var _persondb;

}
```

Comment: i will try it however i am using bloc not need to create StatefulWidget

Comment: I understand you but the error say you have to initialise the stated mehtod

Comment: and also the same problem

Comment: it gives other error The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building KeyedSubtree-[GlobalKey#332e6]:
'values'
method not found
Receiver: null
Arguments: []